# Using GL_TEXTURE_2D and GL_TEXTURE_3D together

Tags: opengl, opentk, monobjc

## Preface

I have a test application that draws the following:

[image]

The left triangles are drawn via:

```
GL.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        GL.glColor4d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
        GL.glVertex2d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
        GL.glColor4d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
        GL.glVertex2d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
        GL.glColor4d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
        GL.glVertex2d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
    }
}
GL.glEnd();
```

The right triangles are drawn with:

```
GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

GL.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
{
    GL.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); GL.glVertex2f(0, 1);
    GL.glTexCoord2f(0, 0); GL.glVertex2f(0, 0);
    GL.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); GL.glVertex2f(1, 0);
    GL.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); GL.glVertex2f(1, 1);
}
GL.glEnd();
```

The texture is rendered via FBO.

## The problem

I have a hard time making GL_TEXTURE_2D and GL_TEXTURE_3D to play together. Everything works great until I uncomment the following section of code:

```
GL.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
// GL.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_3D);
```

As a result I get the following image (2D texture stops working):

[image: None]

Is there a way to make 2D and 3D textures work together? I need to render a 3D texture into 2D texture via FBO. Is there a way to do that?

## Full source code

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics;

using ManOCL;
using Monobjc.OpenGL;

using TextureTarget = OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.TextureTarget;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void InitViewport(INativeWindow wnd, IGraphicsContext ctx)
        {
            GL.glViewport(0, 0, wnd.Width, wnd.Height);
            GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
            GL.glLoadIdentity();
            GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
            GL.glLoadIdentity();
            
            Double aspect = 1;
            
            if (wnd.Height > 0)
            {
                aspect = wnd.Width / (double)wnd.Height;
            }

            Double square = 2;
            
            Double realWidth = square * aspect;
            
            GL.glOrtho(-realWidth * 0.5, realWidth * 0.5, -square * 0.5, square * 0.5, -1, 1);
                
            ctx.Update(wnd.WindowInfo);
        }
        
        static void InitGL(INativeWindow wnd, IGraphicsContext ctx)
        {
            GL.glShadeModel(GL.GL_SMOOTH);

            GL.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//          GL.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_3D);
            
            GL.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
            GL.glBlendFunc(GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

            GL.glDisable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            
            GL.glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            GL.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        }
        
        static uint CreateTexture2D(Int32 width, Int32 height)
        {
            uint texture;
            
            GL.glGenTextures(1, out texture);
            GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
            GL.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, IntPtr.Zero);
            GL.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
            GL.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
            GL.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_CLAMP);
            GL.glTexParameterf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_CLAMP);
            GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
            
            return texture;
        }

        static uint CreateFBO()
        {
            uint fbo;
            
            GL.glGenFramebuffers(1, out fbo);
                        
            return fbo;
        }
        
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Int32 strips = 32;
            Int32 stripComponents = 6;
            
            Random rand = new Random();
            
            INativeWindow wnd = new OpenTK.NativeWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", GameWindowFlags.Default, GraphicsMode.Default, DisplayDevice.Default);
            IGraphicsContext ctx = new GraphicsContext(GraphicsMode.Default, wnd.WindowInfo);
            
            wnd.Visible = true;
            wnd.Resize += delegate { InitViewport(wnd, ctx); };
            wnd.KeyPress += delegate(object sender, OpenTK.KeyPressEventArgs e) {
                if (e.KeyChar == 'q')
                {
                    wnd.Close();
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar == '=' || e.KeyChar == '+')
                {
                    Size size = wnd.Size;
                    Point location = wnd.Location;
                    
                    wnd.Location = new Point(location.X - 16, location.Y);
                    wnd.Size = new Size(size.Width + 32, size.Height + 32);
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar == '-')
                {
                    Size size = wnd.Size;
                    Point location = wnd.Location;
                    
                    wnd.Location = new Point(location.X + 16, location.Y + 44);
                    wnd.Size = new Size(size.Width - 32, size.Height - 32);
                }
            };
            
            ctx.MakeCurrent(wnd.WindowInfo);
            ctx.LoadAll();
            
            InitGL(wnd, ctx);           
            
            Int32 width = 512;
            Int32 height = 512;
            
            uint fbo = CreateFBO();
            uint texture = CreateTexture2D(width, height);
            
            GL.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
            {
                GL.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
                
                GL.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
                {
                    GL.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
                    
                    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
                    GL.glLoadIdentity();
                    GL.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
                    GL.glLoadIdentity();
                    
                    GL.glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1);
                    
                    GL.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0f);
    
                    GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                    
                    GL.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLES);
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                        {
                            GL.glColor4d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
                            GL.glVertex2d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
                            GL.glColor4d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
                            GL.glVertex2d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
                            GL.glColor4d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
                            GL.glVertex2d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
                        }
                    }
                    GL.glEnd();
                }
                GL.glPopAttrib();
            }
            GL.glBindFramebuffer(GL.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
            
            InitViewport(wnd, ctx);
            
            while (wnd.Exists)
            {
                GL.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                
                GL.glPushMatrix();
                GL.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_TEXTURE_BIT | GL.GL_CURRENT_BIT);
                {
                    GL.glTranslatef(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);
                    
                    GL.glPushMatrix();
                    GL.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_TEXTURE_BIT | GL.GL_CURRENT_BIT);
                    {
                        GL.glTranslatef(-0.5f, 0f, 0);
                        
                        for (int strip = 0; strip < strips; strip++)
                        {
                            GL.glBegin(GL.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
                            {
                                for (int stripComponent = 0; stripComponent < stripComponents; stripComponent++)
                                {
                                    GL.glColor4d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
                                    GL.glVertex2d(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
                                }
                            }
                            GL.glEnd();
                        }
                    }
                    GL.glPopAttrib();
                    GL.glPopMatrix();

                    GL.glPushMatrix();
                    GL.glPushAttrib(GL.GL_TEXTURE_BIT | GL.GL_CURRENT_BIT);
                    {
                        GL.glTranslatef(0.5f, 0f, 0);
                        
                        GL.glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
                        
                        GL.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
                        
                        GL.glBegin(GL.GL_QUADS);
                        {
                            GL.glTexCoord2f(0, 1); GL.glVertex2f(0, 1);
                            GL.glTexCoord2f(0, 0); GL.glVertex2f(0, 0);
                            GL.glTexCoord2f(1, 0); GL.glVertex2f(1, 0);
                            GL.glTexCoord2f(1, 1); GL.glVertex2f(1, 1);
                        }
                        GL.glEnd();
                    }
                    GL.glPopAttrib();
                    GL.glPopMatrix();
                }
                GL.glPopAttrib();               
                GL.glPopMatrix();
                
                ctx.SwapBuffers();
                wnd.ProcessEvents();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenGL has a precedence of texture targets: GL_TEXTURE_3D overrides GL_TEXTURE_2D, which overrides GL_TEXTURE_1D. Since only one target can be active in a texture unit at a time, the texture target with the higest precedence will supply the sampling data.

To use multiple texture at the same time (independent of their target) you must use multitexturing. Look at multitexturing tutorials to understand how to use them. There are some subtle differences between how your use multitexturing in fixed pipeline, vs. programmable (=shaders) pipelines. http://www.clockworkcoders.com/oglsl/tutorial8.htm